# Submitting an ios app to the app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode4.2

I have been looking following tutorials online for the past two days and I can not get anywhere.

Can someone please give me step by step instructions on how to submit my app to the app store for xcode 4.2.

I have an xcode project ready to go, but the submission process seems to be ridiculously convoluted. I know this question has already been asked but the past answers aren't helping me.

Comment: In what way are the previous questions not helping? In what way is Apple's documentation not sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple recently added [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) to their iOS Developer Library. It includes instructions on how to write Objective-C, get started with the framework and, most importantly, [Your First App Store Submission](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375). Here Apple details the process for submitting applications for review.